# Google Maps - cannot zoom and move at the same time with animateCamera, but can with moveCamera

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am using Google Maps for Android. I need to move the camera to a location and zoom in at the same time.

I build my `CameraUpdate` like so:

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(latLng)
        .zoom(zoom)
        .build();
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
```

Then animate it:

```
map.animateCamera(update);
```

This produces the desired result of moving the camera to the target location. However, it does not zoom in the camera at all. If I use `moveCamera` instead with the same `update` object:

```
map.moveCamera(update);
```

I can see both the movement and the zoom taking effect (without the required animation)

What could be causing the inconsistency in behaviour between `animateCamera` and `moveCamera`? How can I configure `animateCamera` to both move and zoom at the same time?

Comment: Worth noting that no bug for this exists in the Maps bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue! It was in the cluster click listener:

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(
     new OnClusterClickListener<MyClusterItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                     .target(latLng)
                     .zoom()
                     .build();
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                mMap.animateCamera(update);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

The issue is returning false from the `OnClusterClickListener`. Although this is undocumented, presumably it works like the rest of Android and indicates whether the click event was consumed or not. By setting it to false, the click event likely propagated through to the `GoogleMap` object, which must have some functionality of its own that cancelled the zoom.

Comment: The exact same thing was happening to me. 'return true' fixed it. Sounds like a bug...

Answer (score 2):

you should use [CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngZoom(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float))

```
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the issue is the same.

Comment: please post your code as it works for me with no problem

Comment: where are calling animateCamera from

Comment: The code is the same as what you have posted. `animateCamera` is being called from a click listener. This listener is firing as expected.

Comment: first of all, rebuild the project, and then try this code
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40.709475, -73.818740), 14));

Comment: Thank you, but the issue remains.

Comment: just to make sure you asking for animation that is similar to google maps app when you press the current location button but to custom location.

Comment: That's correct, yes. The idea is that the user clicks the cluster, a listener fires and the camera moves to the position of the cluster while zooming in a little.

Answer (score 1):

A poor workaround is to perform the zoom in a separate call to `moveCamera` right before `animateCamera`:

```
CameraPosition zoomCameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .zoom(zoom)
        .build();
CameraUpdate zoomUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(zoomCameraPosition);
mMap.moveCamera(zoomUpdate);

CameraPosition moveCameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(latLng)
        .build();
CameraUpdate moveUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(moveCameraPosition);
mMap.animateCamera(moveUpdate);
```

This is not a fully satisfactory answer though - the movement will animate but the zoom will be instant. It looks very jerky. I am looking for a more correct answer.